# How can I kill Odoo running locally on Linux (Mint)

Tags: linux, odoo, linux-mint, odoo-15

I installed the Odoo Debian package ([from here](https://www.odoo.com/page/download)). Now it just started running and I can't stop it. I want to start it again with a different config file but I can't find a way to kill the instance that is currently running.

I have tried to find the process using  `fuser 8069/tcp` and `lsof -i:8069` but there are no processes shown.

Odoo is not on my list of Startup Applications yet even after reboot it is still running.

How can I kill it? And how can I prevent it from starting on reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run ps `aux||grep`

Find a process that contains this command `python3 odoo-bin -c odoo.conf`

Take the pid for that process and kill

```
sudo kill -9 PID_HERE
```

Comment: And how can I stop it from starting again on reboot?

Comment: systemctl status will list your current processes, find the config which loads up the odoo by reading and there will path of the config file too. Remove that systemctl config then.

Comment: I found that the service is started by a user `odoo` so was most easily able to identify the pid with `ps -U odoo`.
I was able to prevent Odoo from starting on boot with `sysctemtl disable odoo`.
There was also a file called `odoo` in /etc/init.d which I removed. It didn't make any difference on my system but I imagine it could on others.